# Prove $\Big(\frac{x+1}{x}\Big)^{2/n}$ is irrational for $x,n \in \mathbb{N}, n>2$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

For $x,n  \in \mathbb{N}, n>2$, prove $$\Big(\frac{x+1}{x}\Big)^\frac{2}{n}$$ is irrational.
I'm having trouble with this and I couldn't think of any possible way. Can someone help me or suggest me an idea of how to do this?

Comment: What happens, say, if $x=1,n=2$?

Comment: Oh right, I edited the question! Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\left(\dfrac{x+1}{x}\right)^{\dfrac{2}{n}}= \dfrac{p}{q}\implies \dfrac{(x+1)^2}{x^2}= \dfrac{p^n}{q^n}\implies n = 2m\implies \dfrac{x+1}{x} = \dfrac{p^m}{q^m}\implies xq^m+q^m = xp^m\implies x = \dfrac{q^m}{p^m-q^m}$. Observe that we can assume $(p,q) = 1$ to begin with, and if a prime $r$ divides both $q^m$ and $p^m-q^m$,then $r$ divides $p^m$, and thus $r$ divides $p^m, q^m$, hence it divides $p,q$, and divides $(p,q) = 1$, contradiction $r > 1$. So the claim is proven.

Comment: May I ask why is must be that n = 2m?

Comment: This comes from a simple fact that $\sqrt{x} \in \mathbb{Q} \iff x =\left( \dfrac{a}{b}\right)^2$.

Comment: Pardon my inexperience, but I couldn't really see that. So you mean that since $\frac{(x+1)^2}{x^2} \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\frac{(x+1)}{x} \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow \exists m \in \mathbb{N}, m=\frac{n}{2}$? I don't see that, since $m$ could be half-integer, thus even if $r$ divides $p^m, q^m$, it would not divides $p,q$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If this is $a/b$ with $a$ and $b$ coprime, you have $a^n x^2 = b^n (x+1)^2$.  If $p$ is a prime, how do the highest power of $p$ dividing $a$ and the highest power of $p$ dividing $x+1$ relate?  Similarly for $b$ and $x$.

Comment: So I see that the highest power of $p$ dividing $a = \frac{2}{n}$ highest power of $p$ dividing $x+1$. But since $a$ and $b$ are coprime, one of the highest power of $p$ dividing $a$ or $b$ must be $0$. So I'm stuck here, since I couldn't find any contradiction :(.

Comment: If the highest powers dividing $a$ and $x+1$ are $p^j$ and $p^{k}$with $k > 0$, then since $a$ and $b$ are coprime and $x$ and $x+1$ are coprime, $p$ must divide $a$ and not $b$ or $x$, and $nj = 2 k$.
Thus $k = nj/2$ and $nj$ is even.  If $n$ is odd, $j$ is even and $k$ is a multiple of $n$; if $n$ is even, $k$ is a multiple of $n/2$.  We conclude that $x+1$ is the $m$'th power of a positive integer, where $m$ is $n$ if $n$ is odd or $n/2$ if it is even.  Similarly, so is $x$.  But the difference between two $m$'th powers is greater than $1$.

Comment: I still find this unsatisfying. For the $n$ is odd situation, despite $x+1$ containing the $n$'th power of $p$,  $x$ does not contain the $n$'th power of $p$, because it must be a different prime number ($p$ doesn't divide $x$).

For the even situation though, I think @DeepSea answers can make it.

Comment: If $x+1$ contains a power of $p$, then $x$ doesn't but $a$ does.  The primes that divide $x+1$ and $a$ are not the same primes that divide $x$ and $b$.